# Javascript / jQuery Math not adding up correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, math

I've hit a strange issue where my math isn't adding up, hope someone can help!

If I specify a value then everything works as expected. However if I grab values from variables, everything goes a little pear shaped?!?!

Example.

`$('#mydiv').append(0.5);` results in 0.5 being appended to `#mydiv` - happy days!

However if I do the following...

```
var firstscore = 100;
var secondscore = 50;

jQuery('#mydiv').append(firstscore - secondscore / 100);
```

I end up with 99.5 ???

Does this have something to do with floating point math?

Anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: `jQuery('#mydiv').append((firstscore - secondscore) / 100);`

Comment: `100 - 50/100 = 100 - 0.5` What's wrong?

Comment: `100 - (50 / 100) = 99.5` but `(100 - 50) / 100 = 0.5`, so what is the problem?

Comment: You are getting unexpected (as per you) results because you might be confused with operator precedence. Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence
 for understanding precedence in js.

Comment: Pranav you are correct. It's amazing what a couple of brackets can do!!

Comment: yes it will divide by 100 first, maths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
jQuery('#mydiv').append((firstscore - secondscore) / 100);
```

This is because of Operator Associativity & Precedence.

Read [this](http://www.scriptingmaster.com/javascript/operator-precedence.asp)

Comment: Thanks Mayank.. you are correct. Two little brackets and everything works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var firstscore = 100;
var secondscore = 50;
var temp = firstscore - secondscore;
jQuery('#mydiv').append(temp / 100);
});
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">
  </div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That works too. It's a creative approach Bharat.. a good way to get around OS&P. Thanks!